# Implementing Java based Webservice in Android Applications

Tags: java, android, performance, web-services

I am new to android. We have java based web services like Jersey, Apache Axis2 ...etc. In my application I am requesting bulk of data from the web service.

The problem in my scenario is the data in the Database is keep on increasing over timeline. To request this bulk data my web service should met the following requirements

1) Faster Insertion or Updating using Webservice.

2) Faster fetching of the content through Webservice.

3) Can handle multiple requests at a same time.

4) Less load(parsing) to the client side(android App)

Which framework should I implement in the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jersey and Apache Axis 2 are just frameworks for building web services.

Since Android usually runs on handheld mobile devices with limited power, a REST-based Web Service is desirable, as opposed to a SOAP-based one.

The background is, that the SOAP-format is based on XML and therefore has a lot of overhead compared to the JSON format used by REST services. Therefore JSON is easier and by that faster to parse.

If you indeed plan on developing a REST-based service, you should use Jersey. If you want to build a SOAP-based service use Apache Axis2 and let parsing be done by the `kSOAP API` on the Android client.

**EDIT:** To parse the JSON on your Android client, see [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer LuigiEdlCarno. which library file do we can use in android application to parse the Json ?

Comment: @GeorgeViju I have edited my answer to include a JSON tutorial.

Comment: Ok.Thank you  LuigiEdlCarno

Answer (score 1):

Web services mean HTTP (REST) or XML over HTTP (RPC-XML or SOAP).  Your Android need not know or care which one you pick.  A client can't tell if it's Java, C#, Python, or anything else behind the curtain.

Your real problem is "bulk data".  If you design that badly, it won't matter which web service implementation you choose.